# Searching OneDrive for documents with non-western text via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

How do I search my OneDrive for terms with non-Western characters in it?

For example, I have an Excel file which has the text "Tetsuo" and "悠真" in two separate cells.

Using the [Microsoft Graph API Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I am running the following tests

The following queries return this document as a search hit:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='Tetsuo')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='悠')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='%E6%82%A0') // above query pre-encoded
```

The following queries do not return the document as a search hit:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='真')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='%E7%9C%9F') // above query pre-encoded
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='悠真')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='%E6%82%A0%E7%9C%9F') // above query pre-encoded
```

I know the Microsoft Graph API Explorer is supposed to handle encoding, and it seems to handle it well as the results are always consistent on that level. However, it seems like there is something preventing me from searching beyond one Japanese character. Is there something I am missing?